# How do I go about making a Unix Timestamp in Milliseconds in PHP Code?

Tags: php, json, unix, time

I've tried various things, I want to find out how to specifically do it for now, 7 days ago and 1 month ago.

I tried

```
$timestamp = round(microtime(true)*1000);
```

I got a random number and then E+12 on the end what's that? When I tried to put '`$timestamp`' into a json string to POST to a url to get an array with results within the time periods (which have to be declared in unix timestamps in milliseconds), I get no result back. If I use a unix timestamp converter only and put it into the json string, it works. How I can do this so it's dynamic based on the time in PHP? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`E12` means "multiplied by 10 to the 12th power" otherwise known as scientific notation.  if you want to just output the digits, you can do something like this

```
$timestamp = round(microtime(true)*1000);
echo number_format($timestamp,0,".","");
```

That will output just the number without scientific notation.

To get timestamps for various days you can use `strtotime()`.

```
$microSeconds = microtime(true) - (float)time();
$sevenDaysAgo = (float)strtotime('-7 days') + $microSeconds;
$oneMonthAgo = (float)strtotime('-1 Month') + $microSeconds;

$sevenDaysAgo *= 1000;
$oneMonthAgo *= 1000;

echo number_format($sevenDaysAgo,0,".",""); 
echo number_format($oneMonthAgo,0,".","");
```

Comment: Ok thanks, how could I figure out the timestamp for different days?

Comment: Thanks, will try that.

Comment: 1440624041074 -> that's $timestamp
2878569681926 -> that's $oneMonthAgo

How comes $timestamp is smaller than $oneMonthAgo? if $timestamp is now and that's oneMonthAgo

Comment: I forgot to cast `time()` as a float, it should work now as shown.  If you don't include `+$microSeconds` then your time won't be as precise.  It probably won't make a difference unless you are doing something that requires microsecond precision.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's not needed to be super precise, but I'll add that now thanks :)

Comment: Oh wait, same problem now as before, I leave it without the addition as it works fine for what am doing. :)